# The <Image> component cannot contain children in reactnative

Tags: ios, image, react-native

Error: The  component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on top of the image, consider using aboslute positioning.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Move the views outside of the `<Image>` component.

Comment: Use `<ImageBackground>` when you want to add content inside `Image`

Answer (score 2):

`<Image>` with nested content is no longer supported. Looking into `<ImageBackground>` instead if this is something you did in our app.

```
<ImageBackground
  style={styles}
  source={source}
  resizeMode={resizeMode}
>
```